# How can I tease Sonicwall?

Tags: 14.04, proxy, firewall

In my college, I can't use the web, because they use [Sonicwall network firewalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonicWall)

How can I tease it? For I use all websites in my college?

Please see the result when I access a website blocked

[image: here]

I already tried use non-proxy but it didn't worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I do to get around issues like this: a SOCKS5 proxy over ssh.  If you've got a linux box outside of the network, you can do something like:

```
nohup ssh -D 8000 -C -N user@host > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This will open a secure ssh tunnel to your host, giving you a SOCKS5 proxy on port 8000, and disassociate it with the terminal (so you can close the window without losing your connection. To disconnect, you'd just need to kill the pid.)

Point your browser to your new proxy: localhost:8000, and go.  To get apt to use the proxy, you'd need to edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to containt the following line:

```
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://localhost:8000/";
```

You probably would also want to point CLI utilities through your proxy, so you need to add it to your shell environment:

```
export SOCKS_SERVER=localhost:8000;
```

You can add this to your `~/.bashrc` (assuming you are using bash) to make it available in all (new) terminal sessions.

Comment: Ok, but after that I make this, is possible I turn on and turn off?

Comment: If your goal is to only circumvent the firewall with your browser, I'd suggest using a plugin like FoxyProxy (for Firefox) or SwitchySharp (for Chrome) to toggle between using your proxy, and not.  If you need to enable/disable it for apt access and other CLI programs, you'd need to clear the SOCKS_SERVER env var and comment out the proxy line in apt.conf.

Comment: FWIW, this is something I use so regularly, I wrote a script to manage it for me.  It's running on my Macbook Pro (not ubuntu, but easily converted, I'm sure) that detects when I sleep/wake up.  It'll automatically wait for a network connection, choose the best ssh server available (I prefer my home server, then my colocated server, and finally a friend's server if all else fails), then opens the tunnel automatically for me.  When I sleep my machine, it automatically kills the process.  For me, it's completely transparent, but adds that extra level of privacy and security that I crave so much.

Comment: but this FoxyProxy tease this Sonicwall? Or have you ever tried in this software?

Comment: And this command nohup ssh -D 8000 -C -N user@host > /dev/null 2>&1 & Is for just make a test if the ssh works, or I have to put any user and host?

Comment: `nohup` will disassociate ssh from the shell.  `-D 8000` sets up the SOCKS5 proxy on port 8000.  `-C` enables ssh compression. `-N` tells ssh not to execute any remote commands -- we're creating a tunnel, not logging in to get a shell.  SSH will connect, and do nothing else.  `user@host` is your username at the remote machine.  e.g. you could do something like myuser@192.168.1.1, if you were connecting as myuser to 192.168.1.1.  `> /dev/null 2>&1` redirects ALL output (stdout and stderr) to /dev/null, so you're not creating any logs or anything.  Finally, `&` backgrounds the process.

Comment: And this user@host when I use ssh, can possible I use in any user and in any host? Or is necessary use a specific user and host?

Comment: You will need to have your own endpoint.  This could be a server you host somewhere, or just another computer you can SSH to that's outside the network. That part will be up to you to figure out.

Comment: Didn't work for me please see here http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/captura_de_tela_de_2014-08-22_17_57_33-png

Comment: But for me works just if I do ssh -D8000 -p22 user@yourserver.example.com and after point my browser to your new proxy: localhost:8000